# Chrome extension - replace POST data with preset values in the extension

Tags: post, google-chrome-extension, http-post

I'm feeling a little bit idiotically when asking for this, but I really need your help with building this, because my knowledge about Javascript and Chrome development is still very poor. I have this simple HTML page with experimental form on it

http://alcatra.ideatech.cz/chrome_plugin_experiment.php

**chrome_plugin_experiment.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<body>
<div class="content">
    <div class="heading">
        <h2>Chrome Plugin Experiment</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="formdiv">
        <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-div-name-class">
                Name: <input type="text" name="experiment-chrome-testname" class="form-input-name-class" id="form-input-name-id">
            </div><br>
            <div class="form-div-favcolor-class">
                Favourite color: <input type="text" name="experiment-chrome-testfavcolor" class="form-input-favcolor-class" id="form-input-favcolor-id">
            </div><br>
            <div class="form-div-submit-button">
                <input type="submit" name="experiment-chrome-submit" class="form-input-submit-class" id="form-input-submit-id">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**welcome.php**

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <b><?php echo $_POST["experiment-chrome-testname"]; ?></b>, how are you?<br>
You said your favourite color is: <b><?php echo $_POST["experiment-chrome-testfavcolor"]; ?></b>

</body>
</html>
```

and I need to build a very simple Chrome extension, which will be **active on every page** I visit and only on pages where is `<input name="experiment-chrome-testname">` and `<input name="experiment-chrome-testfavcolor">` in the HTML code, this plugin will do its work. I need this extension to **grab the submitted form POST data and replace them with values preset in the extension**, so the result page will show these different values than I originally typed into the form.

*Example:* When I type any name (e.g.'David') into the name field and any color (e.g. 'red') into color field, after I click the submit button, my extension will replace 'David' --> 'Peter' and 'red' --> 'blue', where 'Peter' and 'blue' are **manually set somewhere in JavaScript code in the extension**. I will be redirected to page 'welcome.php' and I will see:

```
Welcome Peter, how are you?
You said your favourite color is: blue
```

even in case I typed anything different in the previous form.

I will be sincerely grateful to anyone who will write this for me or explain me how I have to proceed at least. Please don't blame me, I've spent some hours with googling, but I still haven't understood what should be placed into background script and what else into content script in my case.

Comment: Still no ideas ppl? :,-(

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use extension rather than pure JavaScript? In pure JavaScript, you can use

```
var myForm = document.getElementById("myFormId");
```

to get your form first, then add event listener to that and modify the post data.

```
myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {...});
```

BTW, according to [Issue 91191](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91191), we can't modify form data in chrome extension now.